# C++ threads: cannot unlock mutex in array after condition_variable wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I am trying to synchronize one main thread with N children threads. After some reading, I used `condition_variable` and `unique_lock`. However, I always get the errors `condition_variable::wait: mutex not locked: Operation not permitted` or `unique_lock::unlock: not locked: Operation not permitted`, in OS X. In Linux, I get `Operation not permitted` only.

To be clearer: my goal is to get a sequence of prints:

```
main thread, passing to 0
thread 0, passing back to main
main thread, passing to 0
thread 0, passing back to main
...
```

for each of the four threads.

I adapted the code from the example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable. This example uses `unlock` after `wait`, and it works wonderfully with only one thread other than main (N=1). But when adapted to work with N>1 threads, the error above happens.

Yam Marcovic said in the comments that I should not use `unlock`. But then, why does the cppreference example use it? And why does it work well with one main and one other threads?

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

constexpr int N_THREADS = 4;
constexpr int N_ITER = 10;

bool in_main[N_THREADS] = {false};

void fun(mutex *const mtx, condition_variable *const cv, int tid){
    for(int i=0; i<N_ITER; i++) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(*mtx);
        // Wait until in_main[tid] is false
        cv->wait(lk, [=]{return !in_main[tid];});
        // After the wait we own the lock on mtx, which is in lk
        printf("thread %d, passing back to main\n", tid);
        in_main[tid] = true;
        lk.unlock(); // error here, but example uses unlock
        cv->notify_one();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // We are going to create N_THREADS threads. Create mutexes and
    // condition_variables for all of them.
    mutex mtx[N_THREADS];
    condition_variable cv[N_THREADS];
    thread t[N_THREADS];
    // Create N_THREADS unique_locks for using the condition_variable with each
    // thread
    unique_lock<mutex> lk[N_THREADS];
    for(int i=0; i<N_THREADS; i++) {
        lk[i] = unique_lock<mutex>(mtx[i]);
        // Create the new thread, giving it its thread id, the mutex and the
        // condition_variable,
        t[i] = thread(fun, &mtx[i], &cv[i], i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i < N_ITER*N_THREADS; i++) {
        int tid=i % N_THREADS; // Thread id
        // Wait until in_main[tid] is true
        cv[tid].wait(lk[tid], [=]{return in_main[tid];});
        // After the wait we own the lock on mtx[tid], which is in lk[tid]
        printf("main thread, passing to %d\n", tid);
        in_main[tid] = false;
        lk[tid].unlock(); // error here, but example uses unlock
        cv[tid].notify_one();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<N_THREADS; i++)
        t[i].join();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
thread 0, passing back to main
main thread, passing to 0
thread 1, passing back to main
thread 0, passing back to main
main thread, passing to 1
thread 2, passing back to main
thread 1, passing back to main
main thread, passing to 2
thread 2, passing back to main
thread 3, passing back to main
main thread, passing to 3
main thread, passing to 0
thread 3, passing back to main
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: unique_lock::unlock: not locked: Operation not permitted
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Remove `lk[i%4].unlock()` from main, for starters.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? What result do you expect in your in_main variable at the end of execution ?

Comment: >Remove lk[i%4].unlock() from main, for starters

This is the part that gives the error. But why? In this example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable you own the lock after waiting, and so need to unlock it

Comment: This code is really hard to follow. Can you comment it up? Or, better yet, simplify it? At first glance you seem to be waiting/notifying in _both_ threads on the same condition variables, or something?

Comment: > What are you trying to do?

I am trying to get a certain ordering of prints.
"out thread, iteration n" , where n % 4 == m, should be alternated with prints from thread m, "in thread m, iteration l". The ordering between prints of the different threads doesn't matter, only the relative ordering of the prints of that thread with the main one.

Comment: > seem to be waiting/notifying in both threads on the same condition variables, or something
Correct. I'll simplify the code more too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem is. This question [Using std::mutex, std::condition_variable and std::unique_lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371020/using-stdmutex-stdcondition-variable-and-stdunique-lock?rq=1) helped me.

Constructing a `unique_lock` is acquiring the `unique_lock` too. So it must be done inside the loop, just before calling `wait`. The function `fun` looks the same, but `main` now looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // We are going to create N_THREADS threads. Create mutexes and
    // condition_variables for all of them.
    mutex mtx[N_THREADS];
    condition_variable cv[N_THREADS];
    thread t[N_THREADS];
    // Create N_THREADS unique_locks for using the condition_variable with each
    // thread
    for(int i=0; i<N_THREADS; i++) {
        // Create the new thread, giving it its thread id, the mutex and the
        // condition_variable,
        t[i] = thread(fun, &mtx[i], &cv[i], i);
        // DO NOT construct, therefore acquire, a unique_lock
    }

    for(int i=0; i < N_ITER*N_THREADS; i++) {
        int tid=i % N_THREADS; // Thread id
        // Acquire the unique_lock here
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx[tid]);
        // Wait until in_main[tid] is true
        cv[tid].wait(lk, [=]{return in_main[tid];});
        // After the wait we own the lock on mtx[tid], which is in lk[tid]
        printf("main thread, passing to %d\n", tid);
        in_main[tid] = false;
        lk.unlock(); // error here, but example uses unlock
        cv[tid].notify_one();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<N_THREADS; i++)
        t[i].join();
    return 0;
}
```

The only difference is that the `unique_lock` is constructed inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to `unlock` your mutexes many times! look at the code carefully:

```
 for(int i=0; i < N_ITER*N_THREADS; i++) {
        int tid=i % N_THREADS; // Thread id
```

where `N_ITER` is 10 and `N_THREADS` is 4 always, because they are `constexpr` 
we get:

```
 for(int i=0; i < 40; i++) {
        int tid=i % 4; // Thread id
```

so, when `i = 0` the mutex in `lk[0]` is unlocked, and then when `i=4` then `tid = 4%4` so again `tid = 0` and you are unlocking it again! `std::system_error` is thrown in this case.

plus, why are all of these C-Pointers anyway? it's not like anyof them can be null at any time.. switch to references..

also, usually when dealing with array indexes the convention is to use `size_t` and not `int`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However:
" when i = 0 the mutex in lk[0] is unlocked, and then when i=4 then tid = 4%4 so again tid = 0 and you are unlocking it again!" When i=0, the main thread sets in_main[0] to false. When i=4, the main thread is supposed to wait for in_main[0] to be true again. Before continuing and unlocking again, the other thread is supposed to change it. Also, I was under the impression that doing a condition_variable::wait gave the thread a locked lock. Is the bool modification really undefined if it is inside the lock?

Comment: what do you mean "the other thread is supposed to change it" obviously it doesn't

Comment: also, if you put guards aroung in_main then it's fine.

Comment: Is the wait a guard, or not? The example I linked says it is, but apparently not? Also, "obviously it doesn't", Obviously it does, look at the sample output. (note however that I initialized the array to false and so the spawned threads start the printing)

Comment: Sorry, that does undiplomatic. I added a sample output obtained when compiling and running it. It does seem to give control back to the main thread by modifying the boolean.